# My css is not working but there is no error

Tags: html, css, styles

i'm using vs code
i tried :
-removing all other styles but one
-checking all semicolons and tags
-using another browser
none of these worked.

please reply if you have a plausible answer :) thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/body_favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <a class = "one" href = "/index.html">MAIN</a>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="p1">Websites by Froggy Sites!</p>
    <p id="p2">Nelson Mandela - The Promotion</p>
<style>
  html {
    background-color: #0096FF;
    }
  @font-face {
    font-family: neonclubmusic_bold;
    src: url(NEON\ CLUB\ MUSIC_bold.otf);
    }
  @font-face {
    font-family: neonclubmusic;
    src: url(NEON\ CLUB\ MUSIC.otf);
    }
  a.one:link, a.one:visited, a.one:active {
    font-family: "neonclubmusic_bold";
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
  a.one:hover {
    color: black;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: underline brown 5px;
    }
  .p1 {
    font-family: "neonclubmusic_bold";
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    }
  .p2 {    
    font-family: "neonclubmuic";
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
  }

</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you fix the code snippets please? Surround them with ```

Comment: Also please tell us what part of the CSS is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are probably using your CSS without including it or in wrong place.

Try using in `style` tag in `head` section above your `body` or create a new file named for example `index.css` and connect this file to your code.

If you use external version. For example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <title>My site</title>
</head>

<body>

  Other HTML STUFF HERE

</body>
</html>
```

Or if you use `style` tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <style>

        all styling here
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <title>My site</title>
</head>

<body>

   All HTML HERE

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a class name while using: .p1, however it looks like your html is set up with p1 as an id.  To access IDs in css you will need to change the "." to a "#".

ex. #p1{ ... } instead of .p1{ ... }

Answer (score 0):

1. As stated above first you should make sure to reference the elements
   in the proper way, either if you need to do it by class (".") or by
   Id ("#") in the CSS code.
2. I have give some standard order to your code within the HTML
   structure for improving readability.
3. Also there are some typos and invalid spaces.

Check the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/body_favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>

      <style>
        html {
          background-color: #0096FF;
          }
        @font-face {
          font-family: neonclubmusic_bold;
          src: url(NEON/CLUB/MUSIC_bold.otf);
          }
        @font-face {
          font-family: neonclubmusic;
          src: url(NEON/CLUB/MUSIC.otf);
          }
        a.one:link, a.one:visited, a.one:active {
          font-family: "neonclubmusic_bold";
          font-size: 20px;
          color: black;
          text-decoration: none;
          }
        a.one:hover {
          color: black;
          font-size: 25px;
          text-decoration: underline brown 5px;
          }
        .p1 {
          font-family: "neonclubmusic_bold";
          font-size: 30px;
          text-align: center;
          }
        .p2 {    
          font-family: "neonclubmuic";
          font-size: 20px;
          text-align: left;
        }

    </style>

    <title>Main</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <a class="one" href="index.html">MAIN</a>
      <p class="p1">Websites by Froggy Sites!</p>
      <p class="p2">Nelson Mandela - The Promotion</p>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I left the HTML and CSS in one single file as it is in your initial example.